# Splitting one line of a Csv into multiple lines in PowerShell

Tags: csv, powershell

I have a Csv which looks something like this:

```
No,BundleNo,Grossweight,Pieces,Tareweight,Netweight
1,Q4021317/09,193700,1614,646,193054
2,Q4021386/07,206400,1720,688,205712
```

What I first need to do is do some maths with the Netweight column to get two values, `$x` and `$y`.
Then I need to split each line in the Csv, into `$x` lines of data, where each line of data will look like `"AL,$y"`

In the below example, I get the values of `$x` and `$y` for each row successfully. The trouble comes when trying to then split each row into `$x` rows...:

```
$fileContent = Import-Csv $File

$x = ( $fileContent | ForEach-Object { ( [System.Math]::Round( $_.Netweight /25000 ) ) } )
$y = ( $fileContent | ForEach-Object { $_.Netweight / ( [System.Math]::Round( $_.Netweight /25000 ) ) } )

$NumRows = ( $fileContent | ForEach-Object { (1..$x) } )
$rows = ( $NumRows | ForEach-Object { "Al,$y" } )
```

This code works as I would hope when there is one row of data in the Csv. I.e. if `$x = 8 and $y = 20`, it would return 8 rows of data which look like `"AL,20"`.
However, I get an error message when there is more than row in the Csv:

```
Cannot convert the "System.Object[]" value of type "System.Object[]" to type "System.Int32".
```

I hope I've explained that OK and any help is appreciated.
Thanks,
John

Comment: `$x = $fileContent | ForEach-Object { $_.Something }` will result in `$x` being an array of length `$fileContent.Count`, not just a single integer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `ForEach-Object` over and over again, just iterate over the csv once and generate your `$x` and `$y` results one at a time:

```
$fileContent = @'
No,BundleNo,Grossweight,Pieces,Tareweight,Netweight
1,Q4021317/09,193700,1614,646,193054
2,Q4021386/07,206400,1720,688,205712
'@ | ConvertFrom-Csv

foreach($line in $fileContent){
    $x = [System.Math]::Round( $line.Netweight / 25000 )
    if($x -ne 0){
        $y = $line.Netweight / $x
        1..$x |ForEach-Object {"AL,$y"}
    }
}
```

Resulting in `$x` number of `"AL,$y"` strings per row:

```
AL,24131.75
AL,24131.75
AL,24131.75
AL,24131.75
AL,24131.75
AL,24131.75
AL,24131.75
AL,24131.75
AL,25714
AL,25714
AL,25714
AL,25714
AL,25714
AL,25714
AL,25714
AL,25714
```